# How to write variable with string in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, forex

I tried to write text with variable, but I can't

```
aaaa = 121.150
bbbb = 120.100
target = "TP = " + ( aaaa * 0.9 ) + "\n SL = " + bbbb*1.01
plotshape(data , style=shape.triangledown,location=location.abovebar, color=red, text=target)
```

I want the output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put *series* (dynamic) text on the chart you will need to use Pine v4 and `label.new()`. You will only see the last ~50 labels created:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
aaaa = 121.150
bbbb = 120.100
target = "TP = " + tostring(aaaa * 0.9) + "\n SL = " + tostring(bbbb*1.01)
cond = rising(close, 1)[1] and falling(close, 1)
if cond
    label.new(bar_index, high, target, yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = color.red, style = label.style_triangledown)
```

[image]